# Ruby, Interpolating an Array of Strings

Tags: ruby, interpolation

When I interpolate an array of strings, it includes the escape characters for the quotes '\"', how would I interpolate it sans quotes?

```
string_array = ["a","b","c"]
p "#{string_array}"        # => "[\"a\", \"b\", \"c\"]"
```

Comment: Use `to_s` instead? What is "sans quotes"?

Comment: @squiguy: String interpolation just calls `to_s` on the array, so he'd have the same result.  "Sans quotes" means without the quotes.

Comment: In his case messick, the reason the backslashes are there, is because he has called inspect on a string, not string_array. The .inspect method for a string and array are different. (I think)

Comment: @messick I didn't know he wanted to join the elements, but yes you are correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

using `p "#{string_array}"` is the same as `puts "#{string_array}".inspect`

Remember because p object is the same as puts object.inspect

which is the same as (in your case, you called p on a string):

```
puts string_array.to_s.inspect
```

(to_s is always called whenever an array is asked by something to become a string (to be printed and whatnot.)

So you actually are inspecting the string that was returned by the array, not the array itself.

If you just wanted to print ["a", "b", "c"] the way to do that would to use `p string_array` not `p "#{string_array}"`

if you want to join all the strings in the array together, you would use String#join to do so. E.g. if i wanted to put a comma and a space in between each value, like messick, i would use:

```
puts string_array.join(", ")
```

This would output: "a, b, c"

Comment: DOH! thanks for that detailed response. completely forgot p calls inspect. cheers!

Comment: NP! Glad I could help, remember to accept the answer if you are satisfied!

Answer (score 3):

You need to `join` the array elements.

`["a","b","c"].join(', ')`